# Date validation using jquery, prevent entering yeterdays date.

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I am trying to validate a date input field.
I can prevent jquery datepicker to prevent from entering old dates using,

```
 $('#delivery_date').datePicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

But user can still enter date manually. How to prevent or validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// when the field changes value
$('#delivery_date').on('change',function(){
    var today = new Date();
    today = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
    // compare the value of the field with whatever you want to test against
    if($(this).val() > today){
         // if the test fails, change the value to default
         $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks guys....i will try these. As a temporary measure I made the date input field read only....only way to enter date is to pick using datepicker. And in date picker i have disabled past dates.

Comment: remember that all client side code can be by-passed and over-ridden. You must replicate the validation server side to ensure data integrity - client side validation is for user convenience only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#delivery_date').on('change', function(){ 
    var today = new Date();
    if(new Date($(this).val()) < new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, today.getDate()) $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

Comment: hello can you confirm that maxDate is working, as it is not working for me,($('#delivery_date').datePicker({startDate: '01/01/1970', maxDate: "+5"});)   is not having any effect on date selection as I can select any date.