# Validate datepicker not to enter old date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a datepicker input like below that getting the date function onclick event, i want to prevent the user from entering old date, how to manage that? any modification that i can do ? or there are any other datepickers that do the job?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="SelectedDate" id="SelectedDate" onclick="GetDate(this);">
```

this is the calender im using [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/HTMLDatePicker.htm)

Comment: There are dozens of datepicker controls -- are you referring to the jquery UI component (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?  If so, show also your initialization code; something like  `$( "#SelectedDate" ).datepicker({ })` ...

Comment: Can you please check the link above to see the datepicker im using

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date validation using jquery, prevent entering yeterdays date.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218203/date-validation-using-jquery-prevent-entering-yeterdays-date)

Comment: Ah yes, the DHTML datepicker from 2005. Let me see what I can do...

Comment: Not a duplicate, @Saswat -- using a different control.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the datepicker not to allow input before today? If it's a jqueryui datepicker, then the code is just:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

There are various other options (offsets in months, etc.); the option is documented [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max).

Answer (score 0):

try this,`$("#datepicker").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() });`

Answer (score 0):

OK, using the DHTML datepicker, look for the three lines in GetDate() that read

```
m=sm;
d=sd;
y=sy;
```

That should be line 28. Add this:

```
if ( new Date(y, m, d) < now ) {
    y = now.getFullYear();
    m = now.getMonth();
    d = now.getDate();
}
```

Hope that helps. By the by, unless you're heavily invested in this old datepicker, I'd recommend you pick another one that has wider support.

Comment: OK, nothing is working, i'll use another datepicker, thanks for your help.